# How to order custom posts by one of the custom fields value, 'date'?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am using this php code to display a list of gigs, which is a custom post type. I want to order it by the 'when' value of the post, and omit the gigs that have already happened. 
How can I modify the following code to get that happening?

```
    <?php
$args2 = array(

    'post_type' => 'gig',
    'numberposts' => -1
);
$gigs = get_posts($args2);
foreach ($gigs as $gig){
    echo '<h2>'.$gig->post_title.'</h2><br />';
    // for each custom fields you want.
    echo get_post_meta($gig->ID,'_gigswhen', true).'</br>';
    echo 'Time: '.get_post_meta($gig->ID,'_gigsstart_time', true).'-'.get_post_meta($gig->ID,'_gigsend_time', true).'<br />';
}
?>
```

TO clarify a bit, here is the code in my functions.php

```
    $config = array(
        'id' => 'gigs-info',
        'title' => 'Gig Info',
        'pages' => array('gig'),
        'context' => 'normal', 
        'priority' => 'high', 
        'fields' => array(), 
        'local_images' => false,
        'use_with_theme' => true //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
    );
    $my_meta = new AT_Meta_Box($config);

    //Add fields to your meta box
    $my_meta->addText($prefix.'where',array('name'=> 'Where is the Gig '));
    $my_meta->addDate($prefix.'when',array('name'=> 'When is the Gig '));
    $my_meta->addTime($prefix.'start_time',array('name'=> 'When Does it Start '));
    $my_meta->addTime($prefix.'end_time',array('name'=> 'When Does it End '));
    $my_meta->addText($prefix.'with_who',array('name'=> 'With Who is the Gig '));
    $my_meta->addTextarea($prefix.'words',array('name'=> 'A few words on the gig '));
    $my_meta->Finish();
}
?>
```

I'm using a custom meta-box class file that someone kindly pointed me to. So I'm not sure if it's being saved as a unix timestamp or not.. I'm a bit new to wordpress php pogramming :)

Answer (score 1):

## the best way

If you input the gig time as a unix timestamp (using `strtotime()`), then you can use `WP_Query`'s `meta_value_num` in the `orderby` element to set the order. You can also use `WP_Query`'s `meta_query` to only get posts that have a date that occur in the future.

## the other way

If you can't do this for some reason or another (probably that your date is already set), if you get all the gigs, you can reorder the array of posts based on a `strtotime()` of your meta value. This will be a heavier implementation performance wise, so go with the other one if possible.

Comment: I edited the question a bit, to show you how the user is inserting the gigs on the backend. I created an options page with custom meta boxes, and used a meta-box-class file that stored it all not sure exactly how the date is being stored? 
If it helps, when I enter the date, I pick it from a calendar, and it displays as "feb 21, 2012" for example

Comment: What happens when you get the meta? What format is it in? I see no reason for my method to not work regardless of data storage method. `strtotime()` is way flexible.

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to add "orderby => date, order => ASC" to the array to get what I wanted. thanks!

Comment: That will probably be sorting by the date the gig was posted, not the date listed in the meta...unless you've got some funky hooks and filters on your WP_Query.

Comment: Ah you're right actually... I'm not sure how to do what you're suggesting with strtotime(). If you'd like to elaborate I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: If you feed `strtotime()` a date in string format, it will convert it to a unix timestamp, which is merely the number of seconds since the unix epoch, which makes it superbly easy to do direct comparisons with other times. Does that make it clearer? The php documentation is outstanding, I highly recommend reading that.

Comment: AH got it. I've altered the code so it's storing the dates as a string, which makes them order properly as far as I can tell. 
Now I just need to convert them back to a readable date to display in the event list.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the question solved so that others with similar issues may benefit from your learning

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I'm thinking the ability to "unpublish" or expire a post might be more up your alley. A big part of this is that unless your start_time is in Unix format, WordPress won't really know how to interpret it as something comparable to "now". And I'm assuming you're inserting it into something like a MM/DD/YYYY.

Take a look at some of these plugins, maybe that will get you in the right direction. Hopefully at least one has support for Custom Post Types.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=expire

Comment: Expiring the gigs would be only one of the criteria I'm needing. I want to list them on the page by date as well. even just that would be acceptable for now

Comment: Storing dates in MM/DD/YYYY format will mess up the sorting. YYYY/MM/DD or timestamp would work.